# Auth0 LoginAsync error

Tags: c#, auth0

I have to perform Auth0 authentication process and extract the token.

I have **Authenticator** class as below -

```
class Auth0Authenticator
{
    public Auth0Authenticator() { performAuthentication(); }
    public void performAuthentication()
    {
        Auth0Client auth0Client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions()
        {
            Domain = "mydomain",
            ClientId = "clientid",
        });

        var extraParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        extraParameters.Add("connection", "parameter");

        var result = auth0Client.LoginAsync(extraParameters: extraParameters);
    }
}
```

while executing **LoginAsync** I am getting error - **The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.**

even after creating STA thread or adding attribute [STAThread] not helping.

When i executed the same code in a simple dialog based application, code is successufully returning me the token. but putting the same code in my project(consists of MFC/C#/CLI) throwing error.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). `Auth0Client.LoginAsync` is an async API and you are trying to invoke it in the constructor of your class. This can have negative consequences if there is code dependent on that function completing before being able to perform their functions.

Refactor the code to follow suggested syntax

```
public class Auth0Authenticator {

    public Auth0Authenticator() { 
        //Subscribe to the event
        autoAuthenticate +=  onAutoAuthenticating(); 
        //raise event to allow async operation.
        autoAuthenticate(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private event EventHandler autoAuthenticate = delegate { };
    private async void onAutoAuthenticating(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        await PerformAuthenticationAsync();
    }

    public async Task PerformAuthenticationAsync() {
        Auth0Client auth0Client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions() {
            Domain = "mydomain",
            ClientId = "clientid",
        });

        var extraParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        extraParameters.Add("connection", "parameter");

        var result = await auth0Client.LoginAsync(extraParameters: extraParameters);

        //...do something with the result as needed

        string access_token = result.AccessToken;
        string refresh_token = result.RefreshToken;

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Nkosi..I am facing a problem with this code. When I am creating object of Auth0Authenticator class, before its completion, next statement is getting executed and after some I am again getting the error mentioned in above question.

For instance,

Line1 - Auth0Authenticator auth = new Auth0Authenticator();

Line 2 - //some code

here Line2 is executing before Line1 completes its execution and gives result. after some time Line1 inside code show "calling thread must be STA". Any idea whats happening?

Comment: Got the solution. Authentication must be donefrom STA(or UI thread) in my case. I used  -  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                result = auth0Client.LoginAsync(extraParameters: extraParameters);
            }));
and that solved the problem.